# Strange spacing for CSS table using fractional heights

Tags: html, css

Edit: Sorry folks, looks like this was dumb JS bug I missed. It was inserting multiple empty rows in between each legitimate row. I'm not sure why they only start to show up near the bottom but it was because for every 1 real row there were 3 duplicate empty rows in between.

[image: Image of strange table spacing issue]

Every TD in the above table has the following classes/styles:

```
.cell
{
    background-color: lightgray;
    opacity: 1.0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hour
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 8.33%
}
```

I imagine the 8.33% height is to blame but I have 12 rows and I want each of them to be 1/12th the height of the table. Is there a better way to do this that doesn't create weird gaps other than specifying a static number of pixels?

Comment: Ca you share you complete code

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue like @maxspan has said we need more of your source code to figure out the problem

Comment: Ditto... It seems to work for me. So you are likely missing something else.